# pagination controls is not working in ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I want to add `pagination controls` in my Ionic application so I install `npm i ngx-pagination`
and I import it in my `app-modules.ts`.

I made this copy of my application to test it with local table after that it will be linked to a data base but us you can see when I click to `page 2`  or `page 3` is not working it is stack on `page 1`

please can you help me

here you can see the image of my application :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyPER.png)

here you can see the HTML code :

```html
<table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>مجموع</th>
      <th>تم</th>
      <th>مثبت</th>
      <th>الاسم و اللقب</th>
      <th>عون الجرد</th>
    </tr>
    <tr
      routerLink="/invo-list"
      *ngFor="let item of employeeL | paginate:{itemsPerPage:5,currentPage:1}"
    >
      <td>20</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td><ion-checkbox slot="end"></ion-checkbox></td>
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
      <td>{{item.matricule}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event"></pagination-controls>
```

here the ts file

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-folder',
  templateUrl: './folder.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./folder.page.scss'],
})

export class FolderPage implements OnInit {
p: Number=1;
   employeeL=[
     {matricule:1125,name:'ali',lastname:'ben mohammed'},
     {matricule:1295,name:'muhammed',lastname:'salah'},
     {matricule:1132,name:'youssef',lastname:'najjar'},
     {matricule:1196,name:'mohssin',lastname:'ben moussa'},
     {matricule:1295,name:'muhammed',lastname:'salah'},
     {matricule:1132,name:'youssef',lastname:'najjar'},
     {matricule:1295,name:'muhammed',lastname:'salah'},
     {matricule:1132,name:'youssef',lastname:'najjar'},
     {matricule:1295,name:'muhammed',lastname:'salah'},
     {matricule:1132,name:'youssef',lastname:'najjar'},
     {matricule:1295,name:'muhammed',lastname:'salah'},
     {matricule:1132,name:'youssef',lastname:'najjar'},
     {matricule:1295,name:'muhammed',lastname:'salah'},
     {matricule:1132,name:'youssef',lastname:'najjar'}]

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.folder = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

  }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<tr
  routerLink="/invo-list"
  *ngFor="let item of employeeL | paginate:{itemsPerPage:5,currentPage:p}"
>
```

`currentPage` should be change with `p`.

Comment: It's my pleasure to help you to make it useful.

Comment: sorry i can't make it useful I don't have `15 reputation score`

Comment: No worry, I didn't mean you should check it as useful for my answer. Just hoped it will be helped for you. Thank you. :)